3 zone baseboard heat boiler water heater triggers zone 1 when heating
In the summer with all 3 zone thermostats turned to off, should zone 1 trigger the baseboard heat registers whenever the boiler turns on for the water heater (I’ve even removed zone 1 thermostat)?

How hot is zone 1 getting?  Piping hot throughout, as in winter?   Or a little hot in places?  Zone 1 thermostat should control zone 1 valve.  Can you check that valve is closed?  You can check temperature of pipe several feet up and down stream from that valve?  If possible to take a picture of the pipe arrangement including all the zone valves, pumps,  and the heater that would help.

Is there a pump running or a zone valve opening for zone 1? Probably not, I'd guess.
The usual reason for a zone to heat when the boiler fires for hot water only, and the zone is not calling for heat, is thermo-syphoning and lack of heat traps in the piping system to prevent thermo-syphoning.
Thermo-syphoning is the movement of warm or hot water up and cold or cooler water down just due to the density differences of the water, without a pump involved.
Alternate possibilty if the water heater is a zone and the pump is shared (rather than one pump per zone) would be a zone valve that's stuck open on Zone 1.
